# javascript webpage using Google maps doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript

I created a simple Google Maps webpage using Javascript. I parse an XML file and display a series of markers on a map of the Korean city I live in.  Works great in all browsers on a windows machine but doesn't work at all when I access the same page on my Android phone. I get all the html of the web page, including menus, ads, etc, but the map is not even shown at all. 
Hooked the phone up to Eclipse and checked the log, but no errors I could see.  Anyone know any reason why Android would have trouble showing a Google Maps page?

If you want to see the code, it's here:
    http://ulsanonline.com/ulsanmap.php 
and the javascript I use to populate the map is below:

```
function detectBrowser() {
  var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
  var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
    mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
    mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
  } else {
    mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
    mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
  }
}

var markersArray = new Array();
var map;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.543401,129.340954);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    detectBrowser();

    var dine_image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      '/Maps/dine.png',
      new google.maps.Size(50,50),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(25,50)
    );
    var drink_image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      '/Maps/drink.png',
      new google.maps.Size(50,50),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(25,50)
    );

    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
     '/Maps/shadow.png',
     new google.maps.Size(78,50),
     new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     new google.maps.Point(25,50)
    );


   // read the xml file
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else  {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","/uoplaces.xml",false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
   xml=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("place");

   // parse xml
   for (i=0; i < xml.length; i++) {
       var name = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
       var type = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].getAttribute("category");
       var link = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
       var lat = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue / 1000000;
       var long = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("long")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue / 1000000;


       var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
         '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + name + '</h1>'+
         '<a href=' + link + '>' + 'More Info' + '</a>'+
         '</div>';


       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
       if (type == "restaurant") {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatlng,
             map: map,
             type: type,
             icon: dine_image,
             shadow: shadow,
          html: contentString
      });
   }
   else {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatlng,
         map: map,
         type: type,
         icon: drink_image,
         shadow: shadow,
         html: contentString
          });
       }

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
       })(marker, i));

       markersArray.push(marker);

    } // parse

    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(map);
    }

} //end function initialize



// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
function clearOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

// Shows any overlays currently in the array
function showOverlays(category) {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      if (markersArray[i].type == category) {
         markersArray[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've actually created an Android app using the same GoogleMaps API, data and purpose, and it works fine, too. It's just the Android browser or Firefox on Android that doesn't work which makes me think it might be with the XMLHTTPREQUEST done in the initialize() function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your link to download the source for the webpage doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, the problem was with my CSS. I had set the iPhone or Android % but not size.  If I had a desktop/laptop browser the size was set but if I had a phone browser the size wasn't and setting a % of something not set gave me no map_canvas to draw on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including these meta-tags?

```css
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
```

**EDIT :**

Your webpage works on Android 4.0.3. You added some code though I see

```
function detectBrowser() {
  var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
  var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
    mapdiv.style.width = '480px';
    mapdiv.style.height = '600px';
```

> ```
>   var parent = document.getElementById('templatemo_container');
>     var nastylogo = document.getElementById('templatemo_top_panel');
>     parent.removeChild(nastylogo);
> ```

```
  } else {
    mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
    mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
  }
}
```

Though the line "parent.removeChild(nastylogo);" throws "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8"

Comment: I had this one:  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> but I added the ones you mentioned, but that didn't help.  Still just a blank area where the map should be

Comment: and the link is just the url to the actual site's web page. You can view source once loaded into your browser. It should have been http://ulsanonline.com/Maps/ulsanplacemap.php

Comment: I get a web page not found response from your server, plus you need to make a php page downloadable by placing it in a zip, otherwise the webserver will process the php and no one can see the php source.

Comment: wow. now the web page isn't working at all for my desktop browser.  Not my day to be coding

Comment: ok, so whatever I did to test things works on the desktop but still doesn't work on the phone. No errors, nothing.  And you don't really need the php - that's just me web page menu. The javascript does all the mapping code.

Comment: http://ulsanonline.com/Maps/ulsanplacemap.html is the same with the php including menus